# How do I correctly query multiple nested arrays for a string match? - MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I'm trying to build a MongoDB query where I can search a list of objects, which all contain multiple nested arrays of objects, for one where a property on the lowest level contains part of a string.

This is the general structure of theses objects:

```
{
   "name": "Foo"
   "structure": {
       "configs":[
          {
            "combinations": [
                {
                  "title": "item1"
                },
                {
                  "title": "item2"
                }
            ]
          },
          {
            "combinations": [
                {
                  "title": "item3"
                },
                {
                  "title": "item4"
                }
            ]
          }
       ]
   }
}
```

Now when I search for "item1" or just "1", I'd like for that example object to be returned, because the first `combinations`array contains an object with the title `item1`.
Since I'm building the application in Spring boot, usually the queries could easily be handled by the usual high level `findAllByPropertyMatching(String searchTerm)` in the repository class. Due do its complexity this does not work in this case, and I'm really struggling with how to go about this.

I tried a custom query...

```
@Query(value = "{'structure.configs.$[].combination.$[].title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
public List<Item> findAllByStructuregMatchesRegex(String query);
```

...but it has multiple issues, obviously.

Because the data is loaded from an external source, I'm not able to change the underlying data structure. I also can't cache all items and filter it with Java logic, because the data set is way too big.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate your help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error, the solution seems to be pretty straightforward:

```
 @Query(value = "{'structure.configs': {\n" +
            "            '$elemMatch': {\n" +
            "                'combinations': {\n" +
            "                    '$elemMatch': {\n" +
            "                        'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}\n" +
            "                    }\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        }}")
    public List<Item> findAllByStructureMatchesRegex(String query);
```